# How to list tables from accessible via database links?

Tags: select, oracle11g, database-link

I have an access to a database, and sure I can get all tables/columns accessible for me just using:

```
select * from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
```

I can also access some tables using "@", as I understand a database link mechanism, like this:

```
select * from aaa.bbb_ddd@ffgh where jj = 55688
```

where `aaa.bbb_ddd@ffgh` corresponds to some table with a column `jj`

BUT I don't see this `aaa.bbb_ddd@ffgh` table in `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`.

How can I request all tables (and columns inside them) accessible for me via these database links (or so)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, easily, get all columns accessible via all database links; you can get all columns accessible via one database link by querying ALL_TAB_COLUMNS on the remote database

```
select * from all_tab_columns@<remote_server>
```

where `<remote_server>` in your example would be `ffgh`.

If you want to get this same information for *all* database links in your current schema, you'd either have to manually enumerate them and UNION the results together:

```
select * from all_tab_columns@dblink1
 union all
select * from all_tab_columns@dblink2
```

Or, do something dynamically.

[As Justin says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285432/how-to-list-tables-from-accessible-via-database-links/29286867?noredirect=1#comment46771112_29286867), it's clearer if you add which database the data is coming from; you can do this either by just writing it in the query:

```
select 'dblink1' as dblink, a.* from all_tab_columns@dblink1 a
 union all
select 'dblink2', a.* from all_tab_columns@dblink2 a
```

Or by using an Oracle built-in to work, for example the [GLOBAL_NAME](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_5127.htm#REFRN29019) table (there's lots more ways):

```
select db1g.global_name, db1a.*
  from all_tab_columns@dblink1 db1a
 cross join global_name@dblink1 db1g
 union all
select db2g.global_name, db2a.*
  from all_tab_columns@dblink2 db2a
 cross join global_name@dblink2 db2g
```

Comment: If you do `union all` the results from a bunch of queries across different database links, make sure to add an additional column indicating which database link a row relates to.  You might have access to a table `FOO` owned by a user `A` on both the `dblink1` and the `dblink2` database for example.

Comment: @Ben, Justin, it worked perfectly, thanks very much!! but karma"-" to Oracle no way to find the answer for nubs at O.docs